# Avoid page refresh when inserting flash with Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I've got this function

```
function onVideo(vchat, idUser){
        $('#videollamada').html('<div class="videollamada">'+
                                '<div align="right">'+
                                    '<a href="javascript:closevll(0,'+idUser+');">Cerrar</a></div>'+
                                '<div align="center">');
        if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
                    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
                } else {
                    AC_FL_RunContent(
                                     'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
                                     'width', '350',
                                     'height', '240',
                                     'src', 'videochat',
                                     'quality', 'high',
                                     'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
                                     'align', 'middle',
                                     'play', 'true',
                                     'loop', 'true',
                                     'scale', 'showall',
                                     'wmode', 'window',
                                     'devicefont', 'false',
                                     'id', 'videochat',
                                     'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
                                     'name', 'videochat',
                                     'menu', 'true',
                                     'allowFullScreen', 'true',
                                     'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
                                     'movie', '../../vChat/videochat?address=ec2-50-19-75-28.compute-1.amazonaws.com&from=0&to=1',
                                     'salign', ''
                                     ); //end AC code
                }
        $('#videollamada').append('</div></div>');

        usingvll= vchat;
        $('#vll_'+idUser).html('<img src="images/webcamUs.png" width="15" />&nbsp;<img src="images/phoneOut.png" width="15" />');
}
```

It should make visible a space for video chatting. By itself it works, I can load any html and so. The problem comes when I tried to add a little rtmp client in flash. Instead of displaying it within the page, it refreshes the page and only loads the swf in the browser instead.

Anybody know how to load the swf properly, it is, without making the browser refresh?

**EDIT**

This is how AC_FL_RunContent looks like

```
function AC_FL_RunContent(){
    var ret =
    AC_GetArgs
    ( arguments, ".swf", "movie", "clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
    , "application/x-shockwave-flash"
    );
    AC_Generateobj(ret.objAttrs, ret.params, ret.embedAttrs);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that it uses `document.write()` after the document has been loaded. You should post the `AC_FL_RunContent` function

Comment: Use this http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: @d1001001 I was about to, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @d1001001 said, using swfobject instead of AC_FL_RunContent did the trick, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chat/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
function onVideo(vchat, idUser){

        $('#videollamada').html('<div class="videollamada">'+
                                '<div align="right">'+
                                    '<a href="javascript:closevll(0,'+idUser+');">Cerrar</a></div>'+
                                '<div id="swfclient" align="center"><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></div></div>');
        usingvll= vchat;
        $('#vll_'+idUser).html('<img src="images/webcamUs.png" width="15" />&nbsp;<img src="images/phoneOut.png" width="15" />');

        //SWFObject
        var flashvars = {};
        flashvars.address = "ec2-50-19-75-28.compute-1.amazonaws.com";
        flashvars.from = "from";
        flashvars.to = idUser;
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#cccccc";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.align = "middle";
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://50.17.226.114/vChat/videochat.swf", "swfclient", "350", "240", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
}
</script>
```